# How to implement switch user in spring security rest using grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails

I need to implement *switch user functionality* using **spring security rest plugin in Grails 2.4.3**

Comment: Do you mean chain of operations: login as user1 -> logout -> login as user2?

Comment: I need functionality as provided by following link but using spring security rest:http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Switch-User-in-Spring-Security-Grails

Answer (score 1):

Config.groovy changes.

Enable Switch User Functionality

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.switchUser.switchFailureUrl="/admin/switchFailed"
```

Configure the Roles for Switch User, Here we are only allowing users with ADMIN role to switch.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/j_spring_security_switch_user': ['isFullyAuthenticated()', 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/j_spring_security_exit_user': ['isFullyAuthenticated()', 'ROLE_ADMIN']
]
```

Rest Request

To Switch a User via Rest, Send a HTTP Post request to the following URL with username parameter.

```
/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username={userNameToSwitch}
```

**Update:
Above solution is not working with Rest, as Rest uses Access Tokens instead of Session.**

Here is how we can achieve it.

1. Add a new property "originalUsername" in AuthToken domain
2. Implement a new SwitchFilter similar to Springs [SwitchFilter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-security/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.java)
3. This new filter will set the impersonating users username in "username" column and updates the originalUsername with current logged username.
4. Define and add the filter to filterChain in

resources.groovy

```
restTokenValidationFilter(SwitchFilter) {
   // injections
} 
SpringSecurityUtils.registerFilter 'restSwitchFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.ANONYMOUS_FILTER.order + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am writing REST API , so how to use this functionality for REST web service. I am using Spring security REST. I am testing application using Postman.

Comment: Okay It seems like REST needs a bit of work because REST uses AccessTokens.

Comment: Ok. I tried above solution, but its not working due to authentication token. Let me know if there is any article which provide this functionality using REST.

Comment: updated my answer, may be this helps in developing the solution yourself, i will try to do this when i got time.

Comment: I'm about to attempt this for a Grails 3 app. Curious if anyone has tried this yet?